# Using jQuery to append a div, then append more items into the new div without ID's

Tags: jquery

I need to use jQuery to append a div with the class 'address-line' to another element with id 'add-results', and then add several elements to the newly created div. Then repeat this for each item of an object.

Here's what I'm trying to end up with:

```
<div id="add-results">    
  <div class="address-line">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>desc 1</p>
    <img src="thing1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="address-line">
    <h2>title 2</h2>
    <p>desc 2</p>
    <img src="thing2.png" />
  </div>
  <!-- etc repeated on a loop -->
</div>
```

Here's one of the many things I've tried (chdata is the object, chvalue will hold the data):

```
$.each(chdata, function(name, chvalue) {
  $('#add-results').append('<div class="address-line">');
  $('#add-results').append('<h2>'+chvalue['title']+'</h2>');
  // etc.. adding paragraph, an image, some links.
});
```

..but of course that results in this:

```
<div id="add-results">
  <div class="address-line"></div>
  <h2>title 1</h2>
  <p>desc 1</p>
  <img src="thing1.png" />
  <div class="address-line"></div>
  <h2>title 2</h2>
  <p>desc 2</p>
  <img src="thing2.png" />
</div>
```

I've also tried using:

```
$('#add-results').append('<div class="address-line">')
.append('<h2>'+chvalue['title']+'</h2>');
```

..but same result. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `.appendTo` method.

```
$.each(chdata, function(name, chvalue) {    
  $('<div class="address-line">')
    .append('<h2>'+chvalue['title']+'</h2>')
    // etc.. adding paragraph, an image, some links.
    .appendTo('#add-results'); // at last appendTo the #add-results
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Store the new div and reference *that* instead of reusing append. `.append` is going to return the orignal element you're appending to and not the item that was appended. Try something like this:

```
var newdiv = $('<div>',{'class':'address-line'});
newdiv.append(...);
$('#add-results').append(newdiv);
```

Assembled (I prefer leveraging jQuery and the `.text` method instead of passing raw HTML in case that value contains something that could foul the HTML, but to each his/her own):

```
$.each(chdata, function(name, chvalue) {
  // Create and store your new div
  var div = $('<div>',{'class':'address-line'});

  // append the new elements to it
  $('<h2>').text(chvalue['title']).appendTo(div);
  $('<p>').text(chvalue['description']).appendTo(div);
  $('<img>',{'src':chvalue['image']}).appendTo(div);

  // insert that new div into #add-results
  div.appendTo('#add-results');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, Works well. I'm pretty sure the HTML is clean as it's coming from a trusted source thats been pre-formatted, So I've gone with xdazz's method. I didn't know you could appendTo in that way. Cheers.